# PHP и JSON не выводится в ListView список

Tags: android

Есть PHP страница, которая возвращает JSON данные. Написал код, который будет парсить JSON и выводить все это в список

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String LOG_TAG = "mLog";
    ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    final String urlWebService = "https://site.ru/test/getitems.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        new GetJSON().execute();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strs);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);

            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray itemsArray = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject itemsObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = itemsObject.optString("title");

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, title);

                    strs.add(title);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

В этой строчке `Log.d(LOG_TAG, title);` все выводится (т.е. данные в частности заголовок узла выводится в лог), но коллекция оказывается пустой как я понимаю, но не могу понять почему.. Подскажите где ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай так

```
new GetJSON(listView,MainActivity.this).execute();
```

затем

```
  class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        ListView listView;
        Context context;
    ...

     public GetJSON(ListView listView, Context context) {
            this.listView = listView;
            this.context = context;
        }
...
```

затем

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray itemsArray = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject itemsObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String title = itemsObject.optString("title");

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, title);

                strs.add(title);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strs);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А в чем преимущество этого кода?

Comment: @Kolhoznik  Во первых у тебя в коде дофига ошибок.

Comment: Какие? Можете указать?

Comment: 1.Ты не можешь передать обьект в Поток а потом забрать его и передать в Uİ у тебя всегда null будет.Для этого есть интерфейс callback.Почитай

Comment: 2.Поток Асиктаск есть метод onPostExecute только оттуда ты можешь обращаться в Uİ

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPJxnQpb_Vk

Comment: Посматри этот туториал он тебе поможет

Comment: Ок, посмотрю.. А там нормальный способ описан?

Comment: Офигеть вообщето целесообразно взять верным мой ответ.Я показал верны Путь

Comment: Указал твой ответ верным)

Comment: Да его видео уорки тебя многоому научат

Comment: понял, пошел смотреть

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65996/discussion-between-elik-and-kolhoznik).

Comment: Посмотрел я урок который вы порекомендовали. Что-то не нашел я там где он использует callback

Comment: Примерно также сделал только конструкторы и два класса

Comment: Нет callbacka ,там нет у него ооп а каллюак это простой интерфейс загугли

Comment: ок. Спасибо....

Comment: А вообще без callback если сделать как ты сказал с конструктором, это нормально или обязательно Callback обязателен?

Comment: @Kolhoznik я сам не понемал по началу этот калбак .Да конечно каллбак это один 1 методов.он используется не всегда .большей частью делаетяс как я тебе показал сверху и это правильно

Comment: Понял.. В других проектах я никогда не использовал каллбак и ошибок связанных с парсингом или получением JSON не было ранее, да и сейчас нет. А так на досуге почитаю про данный интерфейс.

Answer (score -1):

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); - в этот момент вам список strs пустой, так как не успел уйти запрос на сервер.

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); - нужно добавить после цикла в блоке onPostExecute

Comment: помогло. Спасибо.